# convert HDV video 1440x1080p to an MP4 and MKV using ffmpeg

Tags: video-conversion

I need some help I'm trying to convert HDV video 1440x1080p to MP4 and MKV

film.m2t
Container and general information
MPEG2-TS: 883Mib
1 video streams: MPEG-2 Video
1440x1080 (16/9) , at 25.000 fps, MPEG-2 Video (Main@high-1440)
1 audio streams: MPEG-1 Audio Layer 2

First audio stream
384 Kbps, 48 KHz, 2 channels, MPEG-1 Audio Layer 2

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi1wn.jpg)

[after encode to m4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vZxd.jpg)

scripts:
this one I tried first

> ffmpeg  -y -i "D:\Video\Luke\Late 07 - Early-08\Clip 1\film.m2t"
>   -vcodec msmpeg4 -vf yadif -b 12000k -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 Clip3_H.264_MP3_DIVX.avi

assumed the ffmpeg was adding pillars:

> ffmpeg  -y -i  "D:\Video\Luke\Late 07 - Early-08\Clip 1\film.m2t"
>   -vcodec msmpeg4 -aspect 16:9 -vf "scale=1440:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1440:1080"
>   -vf yadif -b 12000k -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 Clip3_H.264_MP3_DIVX.avi

ffmepg output

> Input #0, mpegts, from 'D:\Video\Luke\Late 07 - Early-08\Clip
>   1\film.m2t':   Duration: 00:04:27.60, start: 0.440000, bitrate: 26104
>   kb/s   Program 100
>       Stream #0:0[0x810]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vZxd.jpg)[0][0][0] / 0x0002),
>  yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25000 kb/s,
>   25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
>       Stream #0:1[0x814]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, 
> stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s
>       Stream #0:2[0x815]: Unknown: none ([160][0][0][0] / 0x00A0)
>       Stream #0:3[0x811]: Unknown: none ([161][0][0][0] / 0x00A1) Please use 
> -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous Output #0, avi, to
>   'Clip3_H.264_MP3_DIVX.avi':   Metadata:
>       ISFT            : Lavf57.28.100
>       Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p,
>  1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 12000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25
>   tbn, 25 tbc
>       Metadata:
>         encoder         : Lavc57.27.101 msmpeg4
>       Side data:
>         cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/12000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
>       Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz,
>  stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
>       Metadata:
>         encoder         : Lavc57.27.101 libmp3lame Stream mapping:   Stream 
> #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4))  
>   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))

side note: if I convert film.m2t to a film.m2ts, aspect ratio and no pillars, but don't want to have to r encode before using ffmpeg

is ffmpeg adding pillars? if I look at the output stream it says

> Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p,
>   1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 12000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25
>   tbc

which matches the input –

> Stream #0:0[0x810]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vZxd.jpg)[0][0][0] / 0x0002),
>   yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25000 kb/s, 25 fps,
>   25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc

except for the video container of course

similar issue when converting to mkv using:

> ffmpeg -y -i "D:\Video\Luke\Late 07 - Early-08\Clip 1\film.m2t" -f
>   matroska -vf yadif -crf 25 -level 3.1 -preset slow -tune film -c:a
>   libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -vbr 5 Clip2_H.264_MP3.MKV

i don't think im changing the aspect ratio and not touching the videos frame size in my scripts when converting, so why the black bars after encoding? am i missing something?

i've just tried

> ffmpeg -y -i "D:\Video\Luke\Late 07 - Early-08\Clip 1\film.m2t" -f
>   matroska -vf yadif -crf 25 -level 3.1 -preset slow -tune film -c:a
>   libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -vbr 5 Clip2_H.264_MP3.MKV

vlc is now saying resolution is: 1440x1080p but it still has pillars

thanks
Gordon

Comment: Is your question actually about avoiding a spurious conversion from 1440x1080 to 1400x1080?  (From your screenshots.)

Comment: no i'm trying to convert 1440x1080 into mp4 and mkv

Comment: okay now you got me thinking lol am i not converting to 1440x1080? typo in the script, 1400x1080 would explain the pillars

Comment: i'll try ffmpeg  -y -i "D:\Video\Luke\Late 07 - Early-08\Clip 1\film.m2t" -vcodec msmpeg4 -vf yadif -b 12000k -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 Clip3_H.264_MP3_DIVX.avi

Comment: Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p, 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 12000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get either of those containers, just `ffmpeg -i infile out.mkv` or  `ffmpeg -i infile out.mp4`.  Not `out.avi`.  The other parameters (resolution, bit rate, deinterlacing) make no difference to either container.  Add those back in as you like.

Comment: fixed this morning t/y :)

Comment: ffmpeg  -y -i "D:\Video\Luke\Late 07 - Early-08\Clip 1\film.m2t"  -vf yadif  -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 clip3_H.264_MP3.MP4